# joomla 2.5! customize login failed notification?

Tags: joomla, notifications

I use standard log in form module in joomla 2.5. If user type wrong password, he only get a notification ***"Failed to authenticate: curl isn't insalled"***. How can i customize this notification. For example, ***"Wrong password. Try again!"*** Thank.

Answer (score 0):

If it's saying that **Curl** isn't installed then you shouldn't be changing the language strings to make it render a different message, as this won't solve any problems.

Contact your host and ask them to enable the PHP **Curl** extension. However I'm not sure why this message is appearing as I don't believe Joomla uses Curl for the authentication scripts. Either way, contact your host.